# Difference between VM CPU usage and GKE container CPU usage

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster of 2 nodes, each node is a VM of 2 CPU on GCE

Here is the chart for VM CPU usage metric
[VM CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weR6t.png)

Here is the chart for CPU usage from GKE containers

[GKE CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O68r5.png)

So why is there much difference between 2 metric? Also why total CPU usage of GKE can be higher than 4 seconds (because I have 4 cores )
[Cluster nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3WHK.png)

PS1 : I found that there is a "bug" or something is not perfect with the chart in stackdriver monitoring. When I change the chart to be 1w then I get something like this
[1w chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkUEB.png)
And if I use 1d chart then it looks like
[1d chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcblv.png)

So now I only have one question left, why total CPU usage from GKE containers are higher than number of cores?

Answer (score 2):

GCE will measure the overall CPU usage of a VM which includes all processes being run (containers, daemons, OS overhead, etc) whereas the GKE container metric only looks at specific container metrics. The container is a single process.

Also, the metric value you are looking at is not utilization; utilization is measured as a percentage, not in seconds as per the [stackdriver metrics reference page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-container). The graph you are looking at shows seconds on the right-hand side, but the important value is the one on the left of the graph which should be a percentage.

The utilization is a percentage of CPU used Vs the total CPU available. At the GCE level this means the CPU used by all processes of the OS Vs the total CPU allotted (2 CPUs). For the container, this is the CPU used by the container process Vs the CPU allocated by k8s. The sum of the containers will not result in the same value as that of the VM, and it is possible for the container CPU utilization to go over 100%

Comment: I know the difference between CPU utilization and CPU usage. CPU utilization is just the label I left on the title. In my question, I mentioned they are CPU usage.

Comment: I agree about CPU usage from VM should be higher than total CPU usage from GKE containers. But I cant understand why CPU usage from GKE is higher than 4 seconds and much higher than VM CPU usage.

Comment: The metrics from the VM will not necessarily be higher than that of the containers. The VM has higher total CPU compared to that of the individual containers so it is normal that the CPU usage and utilization is higher than that of the VM

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand your comment clearly. From what I know there is no term of CPU utilization (percentage) for container, there is only CPU usage (calculated in milicore or seconds) which I'm using at moment for both VM and Containers measurement. My unclear understanding is that why total CPU usage from all GKE containers are higher than 4 seconds and much more than total VM CPU usage while I have only 4 cores in whole cluster.

Comment: Because usage is spread across containers which can be spread across multiple nodes. Look at the breakdown in your screenshot, no individual container is very high. The sum of all containers across multiple nodes (all CPUs) will be higher than that of a single vm

Comment: Basically, this is just funny math from stackdriver. The metrics are always taken over time and the graphs will come.out differently depending on how the metrics over that time period are aggregated. Comparing container performance vs GCE performance simply won't correlate properly because of how the metrics are collected, aggregated and presented

Comment: Also notice the disclaimer on the container usage metric, that the overall metric is not limited by the cores

Comment: I have edited my question a bit because I have just found that the bar drawing is playing role in this issue, in fact, the shorter timeline chart show the average more exactly. I have only one question left why total CPU usage from all containers are higher than number cores I have.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the GKE container CPU usage were not quite correct, we should filter out the container name podsgke...... and container without a name then the chart seems to match with VM CPU usage. I guess these are not a part of workload.