# pods container (podsgke) and CPU usage

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Can someone give me more information for this container process? I understand that this is created and managed by Kubernetes for managing PODs. But the way it takes CPU (almost 30% on top of all containers) is something not usual.

[CPU usage for all containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb8im.png)

Is there anyway we can debug and troubleshoot such issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between VM CPU usage and GKE container CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450227/difference-between-vm-cpu-usage-and-gke-container-cpu-usage)

Comment: are you asking about the docker daemon and the kubelet? these aren't containers, or container processes, they are VM processes

Comment: In this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb8im.png you can see a container which named as podsgke..... and it takes around 30% in total of CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found that podsgke...... is not a part of workload and it is just sum of CPU of some certain pods so it just make the CPU usage almost double. Maybe if some one has more detail information about this then it would be great.